# Disable website to respond request except static files

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have 2 website on my IIS which have the same physical location on disk. Example:

```
www.xxx.com    path on disk : c:\www\xxx.com
img.xxx.com    path on disk : c:\www\xxx.com
```

I want that `img.xxx.com` only response for static files like images, css and js files.

My main goal is to serve static files from a cookieless domain (using `img.xxx.com` for cookieless requests). But if I write `img.xxx.com` to browser i see the same content with `www.xxx.com`. I want to block all request to `img.xxx.com` except images, css and js request.

I dont want to set another folder for `img.xxx.com` because it is very hard for me to change all images url to new url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your idea will work. You need a physically different domain in order to have a truly "cookieless" domain.

> To reserve a cookieless domain for serving static content, register a new domain name and configure your DNS database with a CNAME record that points the new domain to your existing domain A record. Configure your web server to serve static resources from the new domain, and do not allow any cookies to be set anywhere on this domain. In your web pages, reference the domain name in the URLs for the static resources.

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html

Comment: In short, to do it right, you'll need to change all image url's.

Answer (score 0):

I think this idea will work.  There is no way a browser accessing the files via the two different domain names can know that they share the same underlying directory.

The only problem is you need to filter access to just a limited list of file types in the img.xxx.com domain.

You can do this at the IIS level - for example set up an ISAPI rewrite for the filetypes you want to block http://www.isapirewrite.com/.

You will still need to change the URLs in your application (i.e. in the html - from www.xxx.com to img.xxx.com).

I think you also be able to do this using asp.net - by setting up a new asp.net website under the new domain and in a new folder and then setting up a virtual folder in that website linking back to the original folder.  Then you could control access to file types via the new asp.net web.config.  Again you need to change the urls in the html (from www.xxx.com to img.xxx.com/virtual_folder).  I've never tried anything like this though - so maybe there is a flaw in this idea somewhere.

Comment: a cookieless domain needs to be a completely different domain... a subdomain of a domain with cookies will not work.

Comment: I'm in no way an expert on this - but if I set my DNS records to point img.xxx.com to one IP, and www.xxx.com to another IP then there need be no connection between the two.  Why would a browser looking at img.xxx.com even consider the existence of www.xxx.com?  So the argument about subdomains seems unlikely - in fact is img.xxx.com a 'subdomain' of www.xxx.com?

Comment: Just checked a few sites that do this - and it's quite common to see www.xxx.com for the main site and static.xxx.com for the static serving site.  So maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple HttpHandler that check the URL of every request and throw error if the domain is img.xxx.com and the file is not static?

Maybe there's a catch, but as far as I can tell this can work.

(Talking only about the "block all request to img.xxx.com except images, css and js request" part, not cookieless domain part)